# Shared Screen and DVD movies

Tags: dvd-player

I use a new Mac Mini in my stereo system. It has a monitor but does not have Keyboard or mouse. It is controlled with screen sharing from a Mac Book.  My question is related to viewing DVD movies, the store bought kind. With screen sharing active a DVD is inserted into the drive and movie window appears and the sound starts but the playback window is grey.  To get the picture to appear I have to turn off screen sharing. Only then can we watch the movie.

How can I continue to use screen sharing and view DVD's.

Comment: You never actually posed a question in the above text. I recon this is some stupid anti-piracy measure

Comment: go and try vnc instead of screen sharing

Answer (score 2):

This is a silly copy protection measure. If you use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) rather than Apple's DVD Player you get no problem at all.

First, go to `System Preferences` > `CDs & DVDs` and change the setting for `When You Insert a Video DVD` from `DVD Player` to `Ignore` or choose other and select `VLC 2` in your Applications folder.

Now when you insert a DVD VLC 2 will run and should autostart. No grey boxes.

Comment: 6 years later, and this answer is still correct. Apple, providing no warning message at all, turns video into a grey screen when you move to screenshot, screenshare, or screen record. A silly, useless, and annoying copy protection measure. Why build in a DVD player if I'm forced to use VLC?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when viewing something via iTunes. There is no way to watch a video through screen sharing (you get a grey screen both on the host and the client).